# Spring & Docker: Google Oauth2.0 не пропускает запросы с фронта

Tags: spring, docker-compose, google-oauth2

Не могу решить следующую проблему:
Есть три образа докера: бэк на порту [8888->8080], postgresql на порту [5000->5432] и фронт на порту [9000 -> 80]. Всё работает как надо. На бэке запросы проходят: например, если вбить GET-запрос http://localhost:8888/catalog/expenses/types, то получаю результат в JSON-формате, как и ожидается; на фронте по адресу localhost:9000 показывается табличка, которая строится по результату этого GET-запроса /catalog/expenses/types.

Пытаюсь добавить аутентификацию через гугл:
Сформировал на платформе гугла id и secret, поместил их в application.properties, прописал все возможные URI. В проекте добавил два файла:

**SecurityConfig.java:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
          
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .oauth2Login();
    }
}
```

Также добавляю CORS, чтобы клиентский интерфейс мог получать доступ к API из другого источника -
**WebMvcConfig.java:**

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final long MAX_AGE_SECS = 3600;

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
        .allowedOriginPatterns("*")
        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
        .allowedHeaders("*")
        .allowCredentials(true)
        .maxAge(MAX_AGE_SECS);
    }
}
```

Пересобираю проект. Докер-образ фронта не меняю.
В результате если вбивать GET-запрос http://localhost:8888/catalog/expenses/types, то сначала выкидывает гугловскую форму авторизации и аутентификации, после успешного входа показывает всё тот же JSON-ответ, как и должно быть. Но на фронте пропадает табличка, которая строится по этому GET-запросу.

Кто-нибудь может подсказать, что не так?

В основном классе аннотировал с помощью @ConfigurationPropertiesScan() пакет, в котором оба этих файла (и не которые другие, добавленные ранее) находятся. В pom-ник зависимости подобавлял.

Comment: Не вижу как тут докер релевантен. А в принципе - это ожидаемо не работает. Вот сделал фронт запрос, бекенд его перенаправил на страницу гугла, и кто будет пароль вводить? Эту ж страницу получил фронт по своему каналу взаимодействия с бекендом, он же ее не показывает пользователю. Проблема в том, что тут вы сконфигурировали spring boot приложение как клиент, а для доступа к rest API с использованием oauth spring приложение выполняет роль resource server-а (клиентом выступает фронт). Смотрите разницу тут https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth2-enable-resource-server-vs-enable-oauth2-sso

Comment: @RomanKonoval, а как тогда настроить его как сервер ресурсов, можете подсказать хотя бы в общих чертах? Много где упоминаемые аннотации `@EnableAuthorizationServer` и `@EnableResourceServer` считаются устаревшими, и IDE их тоже не одобряет

Comment: Не использовал - не подскажу. Если классы и устарели, то сам принцип остался тем же, скорее всего только способ конфигурации другой, более простой. Я бы начал с документации. По другим разделам спринга - она очень хорошая, уверен, что и дока по spring security тоже не отстает.